# How to apply implicit conversions between tuples?

Tags: scala, types, type-conversion, tuples

I'm experimenting with currying/tupled as an alternative means to pass parameters to a function. In this journey, I'm facing some type difficulties.

I'd like to use implicit conversions to transform a tuple of parameters to the target type. This is what I expect:

Given (REPL example):

```
case class Cont(value:String) // a simplified container class
val paramTuple = (Cont("One"),Cont("2"))
def operate(s:String, i:Int): String = s+i // my target operation
implicit def contToString(c:Cont): String = c.value
implicit def contToInt(c:Cont): Int = c.value.toInt
```

//This works - obviously

```
operate(paramTuple._1, paramTuple._2)
>res4: String = One2
```

//This is what I want, but doesn't work

```
(operate _).tupled(params)
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (Cont, Cont)
 required: (String, Int)
```

Q1: Why the tuple conversion doesn't work? (I'm expecting that an answer to that goes in the lines of: What's required is an implicit conversion between Tuple2[Cont,Cont] to Tuple2[String,Int] but that does not scale up)

Q2: What are my options to have such conversion working? 
Keep in mind that I'd like to have a solution for an N-tuple, so defining a specific Tuple2 to Tuple2 is not really a good solution in this case.  AFAIK, the magnet pattern works similarly, so I hope there's a way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Q1: Why the tuple conversion doesn't work? (I'm expecting that an answer to that goes in the lines of: What's required is an implicit conversion between Tuple2[Cont,Cont] to Tuple2[String,Int] but that does not scale up)

Yes, you've got that right.

> What are my options to have such conversion working?

You could do it this way:

```
implicit def liftImplicitTuple2[A, B, A1, B1](tuple: (A, B))
  (implicit f1: A => A1, f2: B => B1): (A1, B1) =
  (f1(tuple._1), f2(tuple._2))

implicit def liftImplicitTuple3[A, B, C, A1, B1, C1](tuple: (A, B, C))
  (implicit f1: A => A1, f2: B => B1, f3: C => C1): (A1, B1, C1) =
  (f1(tuple._1), f2(tuple._2), f3(tuple._3))

// etc for tuples as large as you need
```

Comment: `liftImplicitTuple2` works beautifully, when called directly and it plucks the proper f1 and f2 from the scope. However I cannot get it to be called implicty, itself. Is there some trick for getting it recognized as an implicit in scope?

Comment: No tricks should be required, as far as I remember (beyond having an expected type, which implicits always need). Do you have an example where it doesn't work?

Comment: I've put the example up as a separate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45596456/why-is-this-implicit-function-not-being-applied