# Why is this implicit function not being applied?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

Trying out the implicit conversion of TupleN proposed by @Alexey Romanov in [How to apply implicit conversions between tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23911151/how-to-apply-implicit-conversions-between-tuples/23911792?noredirect=1#comment78127970_23911792)

Given the following implicits:

```
object ImplicitConversions {

  object A {
    implicit def toA(x: Int): A = A(x)
  }

  case class A(v: Int) extends AnyVal

  implicit def liftImplicitTuple2[A, B, A1, B1](tuple: (A, B))
                                               (implicit f1: A => A1, f2: B => B1): (A1, B1) =
    (f1(tuple._1), f2(tuple._2))
}
```

and the `Tuple` *(1,2)*, I can manually apply `liftImplicitTuple2` and have it invoke the `A` implicit conversion:

```
import ImplicitConversions._

val x = (1, 2)

val y: (A, Int) = liftImplicitTuple2(x)
```

However, if I just try to have `x` converted to `y`, such that:

```
import ImplicitConversions._

val x = (1, 2)

val y2: (A, Int) = x
```

I get:

```
Error:(12, 22) type mismatch;
 found   : (Int, Int)
  required: (sandbox.ImplicitConversions.A, Int)
  val y2: (A, Int) = x
```

Is there some other import I need to get `liftImplicitTuple2` into scope as an implicit?

Comment: Such automagic/stacked conversions are for me evil, clutering the code and negatively impacting the code readability (often w/ few value according other concern)

Comment: We'll have to disagree on that. If you accept implicit conversion for a base type (which is very useful for type safe Customer IDs, for example), then the lack of implicit conversion when inside a tuple makes case classes and other applications of those IDs much less readable, imho.

Comment: Consiveness hiding the complexity/reality far away from the developer "under the carpet" is different from real readability for me

Comment: Yes, implicit conversion can and has been abused, but converting an Int to a `case class CustomerId(v: Int) extends AnyVal` is not complexity, but simple type safety around primitive types

Comment: Do think so, and even is overwelming the type safety. Any `Int` would be automagically converted by calling a `def foo(x: CustomerId)` with an `Int`. If `CustomerId` is "just" an `Int` alias, then `type CustomerId` is much more simple. If `CustomerId` must offer garantee that the value used as `Int` representation respect some constraint, then automagically convert *any* Int is a bad solution for me.

Comment: It is _supposed_ to convert any `Int`. At some point the id comes in as an `Int` whether from input or DB or some other outside source. The purpose of types such as `CustomerId` is that your post ingestion signatures will take a `CustomerId` and you cannot ever accidentally pass an `OrderId`

Comment: But you _can_ accidentally pass an `Int` which is not intended to be an id at all, or which is supposed to be an `OrderId` and hasn't been converted yet. I'd see an implicit conversion from `*Id` to `Int` as more useful, perhaps.

Comment: But there should only be a limited number of places where a `CustomerId` comes in, and making them explicit is generally a better tradeoff than allowing accidental `CustomerId` creation.